# How do i write a script in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file

Just started to learn matlab, I require some help
This is my problem:
Write a script that creates a text file named AwesomeFile.txt. The file contents should be the exact phrase 'Matlab is awesome!'
Your solution should use the fprintf command.

```matlab
file = fopen('AwesomeFile.txt.', 'w')
fprintf = ('file', 'Matlab is Awesome')
```

this was the code I wrote and I got an error

Comment: In your second line, you need to use the variable `file`, not the string `'file'`. You also need to add a `fclose(file)` after.